# "All of the ...." or " All the ... "?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-in-context

I am a bit confused about these two forms

For example :

> John reads books all **of the** time/all **the** time
>
> All **the** students/All **of the** students have participated in march against smoking in the campus

are they both correct?
or it depends on the context?

Answer (score 2):

Using my native-speaker intuition, it seems to me that using "all the" has a more informal connotation, while adding the "of" makes it sound a bit more formal. I don't have any grammar sources but I hope that helped.

Comment: Interesting, my intuition was the opposite. Especially the first example, "all of the time" sounds more informal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a native speaker so won't be able to comment what looks natural but...

The rule says...

Remember, as stated in Swan's PEU, we generally do not use *all of* if the noun **has no determiner.**

> All children can be difficult **NOT** All of children can be difficult.

But then, we can use *all* or *all of* before a noun with or without determiner. In both of your examples, the noun *time* and *students* have the determiner ***'the'*** and thus *all* or *all of* would work.

That said,

> John reads books all of the time **or** John reads books all the time 
>   All the students have ..... **or** All students have....

Answer (score 1):

General grammar rule is:

1. We must use "some, most, any, none" in this way: "Some of the + noun"
2. We can use "all" in both ways: "All of the + noun" and "All the + noun"

So, both of your sentences are correct and it doesn't depend on context.

My reading experience shows that "all the" is more informal and sometimes expressive. You can find it in fiction books, for example. "All of the" is more formal. And, you can find it in official paperwork or some kind of official books.

References

Raymond Murphy, Essential Grammar in Use, 4th edition. Page 172.

Comment: Which grammar books? Which fiction books? Please provide links for your research.

Comment: Raymond Murphy, Essential Grammar in Use, 4th edition. Page 172. I said about fiction and official books in general, you can pick any.

Comment: Also, you should use "What books" instead of "Which books". Word "which" is for cases when we choose among limited and observable amount of choices.